# Why does the sun look odd when merging 360° photos to HDR?

Tags: hdr, 360-panorama, sun, sunset, ricoh

I took some 360° photos with my Ricoh Theta SC2 and planned to merge them to make an HDRI but when I put them in Photoshop to merge, this is what the result is

[image: weird sun merge]

I use HDRIs in blender as lighting and this doesn't seem like a very good image to use for lighting.

I didn't use any special lenses or filters on site I just put my camera on a tripod and let it shoot. is there a way I can fix this or are these photos useless? and what can I do in the future to prevent this?

[if needed here is the link to the photos](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DDv-GjV_1jUN6_fK0PVeVDMaQv173vDK?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you have subscription to Adobe try to use LR Classic, I get there much better results.

Comment: It worked. Looks much better now

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert in HDR, but what I see in PS is this HDRi module do not work well, do not handle well the Sun. Also do not give you some controls you can find in HDR module of LR.

With very fast and dirty HDR make in LR I get much pleasant result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4rvy.jpg
(did not add image inline because I am not certain about the license)

P.S. In LR you can create HDR Panorama (on one step) with all the images which may produce better result.